# What is a good example of an algorithm that is hard to parallelise?

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, factoring, np-complete, inverse-problems

When I have 10 computers, the factorization of a number doesn't scale along.
I am not sure how much faster it would go compared to a single computer, but not 10 times faster like one would expect.

Can someone think of another algorithm where its hard to spread the workload between different machines? Or is this an unique property of factorization?

Comment: Actually Factorization is extremely parallelisable. You probabbly won't get 10 times the speed but you'll get very close.

Comment: You need a problem where each step depends on the previous.  Like simulating a dynamical system or something like that.

Comment: Computing Fibonacci numbers, maybe?

Comment: @bubba unless I'm mistaken you just use exponential approximations which for that so parallelizes fine.:(

Comment: OK. So how about computing Fibonacci numbers *exactly* :-)  I don't know why you would ever want to do this, though, outside of a programming homework assignment.

Comment: @bubba Its no problem that 'no one would ever want to do this'? I'm just looking for a workload, its fine if its unusefull work, as long as it hard to do it in paralell.

Comment: @bubba you will compute them exactly. The closed form solution allows that you just need to do a little math to make sure your precision is right and then you can truncate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short search turned up this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete on wikipedia, which seems to imply that proving something is hard to parallelise is non-trivial in possibly a similar way that NP$\neq$P is hard. Some problems which are thought to be hard to parallelise though, seem to be for example Horn-satisfiability or linear programming.

A problem which is easier to understand but not known to be P-complete would be GCD and extended Euclidean algorithm.